# Laravel Excel import multiple rows

Tags: php, excel, laravel, import, maatwebsite-excel

How to get data from multiple rows in Excel?

Example in this Excel, I want get data from columns `kriteria 1` & `kriteria 2` then save to table hasil "nilai_awal"

[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOjem.png)

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $row) 
    {
        Hasil::create([
            'kriteria_id'   => $row[29],
            'alternatif_id' => $row[30],
            'nilai_awal' => $row[14],
            ''
        ]);
    }
}

public function startRow(): int
{
    return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solve the issue

```
     <?php

namespace App\Clouds;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use App\Models\Record;
use App\Models\Coordinate;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RemembersRowNumber;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class RecordImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithValidation
{
    use RemembersRowNumber;
    use Importable;
    private $rows = 0;

    use Importable;

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            // 'record_date' => ['required', 'date', 'exclude_if:first_pillar_no,null'],
            // 'plan_name' =>  ['required', 'string'],
            // 'locality' =>  ['required', 'string'],
            // 'coordinate_ref' => ['required', 'string'],
            // 'eastings' => ['string', 'required', 'regex:/^\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,3})?$/'],
            // 'northings' => ['string', 'required', 'regex:/^\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,3})?$/'],
            // 'height' => ['nullable', 'string', 'regex:/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})?$/'],
            // 'first_pillar_no' => ['required', 'string'],
            // 'total_points' => ['string', 'required'],
            // 'survey_plan_no' => ['string', 'required'],
            // // 'doc' => ['required', 'file', 'max:5000','mimes:pdf,dwg,dxf,png,jpg',],
            // 'red_is_submitted' => ['required', 'boolean'],
            // 'blue_is_submitted' => ['required', 'boolean'],
            // 'remark' => ['nullable', 'string'],
            // 'blue_delivered' => ['required_if:blue_is_submitted,true', 'nullable', 'string', 'date'],
            // 'red_submitted' => ['required_if:red_is_submitted,true', 'nullable', 'string', 'date'],
        ];
    }

    //     /**
    //  * messages to display for validation error
    //  *
    //  * @return void
    //  */
    // public function messages()
    // {
    //     return ([
    //         'record_date.required' => "Record date field can not be empty",
    //         'record_date.date' => "Only date is accept in recorde date field",
    //         'plan_name.required' => "plan_name field can not be empty",
    //         'plan_name.string' => "Invalid input for plan_name field",
    //         'locality.required' => "Locality field can not be empty",
    //         'locality.string' => "Invalid input for locality field",
    //         'coordinate_ref.required' => "Coordinate reference field can not be empty",
    //         'coordinate_ref.string' => "Invalid input for coordinate reference field",

    //         'eastings.regex' => "Invalid input format for Easting field",
    //         'eastings.required' => "Easting field can not be empty",
    //         'eastings.string' => "Easting field must be letter/number",

    //         'northings.regex' => "Invalid input format for northings field",
    //         'northings.required' => "Northing field can not be empty",
    //         'northings.string' => "Northing field must be letter/number",

    //         'height.regex' => "Invalid input format for height field",
    //         'height.required' => "Height field can not be empty",
    //         'height.string' => "Height field must be letter/number",

    //         'first_pillar_no.required' => "First pillar no field can not be empty",
    //         'first_pillar_no.string' => "First pillar no must be a letter/number",
    //         'total_points.required' => "total points number field can not be empty",
    //         'total_points.string' => "total points number must be a letter/number",

    //         'survey_plan_no.required' => "Plan number number field can not be empty",
    //         'survey_plan_no.string' => "Plan number must be a letter/number",
    //         'doc.file' => "Document must be a file",
    //         'doc.max' => "Document should not be more than 5MB",
    //         'doc.mimes' => "Document must be a file of type: pdf,dwg,dxf,png or jpg",

    //         'red_submitted.required_if' => "Record copy submission date is required",
    //         'blue_delivered.required_if' => "Client's copy delivery date is required",


    //     ]);
    // }


    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'user_id',
            'record_date',
            'plan_name',
            'locality',
            'coordinate_ref',
            'eastings',
            'northings',
            'height',
            'first_pillar_no',
            'total_points',
            'survey_plan_no',
            'doc',
            'red_is_submitted',
            'blue_is_submitted',
            'remark',
            'blue_delivered',
            'red_submitted',

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $rows)
    {



        return new Record([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'record_date' => $rows['record_date'],
            'plan_name' => $rows['plan_name'],
            'locality' => $rows['locality'],
            'coordinate_ref' => $rows['coordinate_ref'],
            'eastings' => $rows['eastings'],
            'northings' => $rows['northings'],
            'height' => $rows['height'],
            'first_pillar_no' => $rows['first_pillar_no'],
            'total_points' => $rows['total_points'],
            'survey_plan_no' => $rows['survey_plan_no'],
            'doc' => $rows['doc'],
            'red_is_submitted' => $rows['red_is_submitted'] == '' ? false : $rows['red_is_submitted'],
            'blue_is_submitted' => $rows['blue_is_submitted'] == '' ? false : $rows['blue_is_submitted'],
            'remark' => $rows['remark'],
            'blue_delivered' => $rows['blue_delivered'],
            'red_submitted' => $rows['red_submitted'],
        ]);
    }


}
```

[image: MY EXCEL EXAMPLE]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try it